# Can we load perl module without ".pm" file extension or some other file extension?

Tags: perl

Can we load perl module without ".pm" file extension?

Can we have perl module with some other file extension such as "dll", "so" or "lib"

Just curious to know, how only "pm" files can be loaded as package/module in perl.

Answer (score 7):

You can load any file you want with `require "file_name";`, with or without extension. The only requirement is that the file is syntactically valid Perl and that it returns a true value in order to indicate that loading the module was successful;

The usual `use Module;` is basically only a shortcut for

```
BEGIN {
  require Module;
  Module->import();
}
```

and `require Module;` (note the missing `"..."` around the module name!) looks for `"Module.pm"` in all the directories listed in `@INC`.

So: `require` with a string loads any file, `require` with a `Bareword` looks for `"Bareword.pm"` in `@INC`.

Comment: While not a requirement, the file loaded by `require` should also use `package`. If not, `do $filename or die $@` makes more sense than `require $filename;`.

Comment: `require` is more than just "`do` for `package`s". `require` also includes code to prevent the file from being loaded more than once. Just because a file doesn't contain a `package` doesn't in any way imply that it should be loaded/executed multiple times.